# Why is my localhost:8000 loading differently from 127.0.0.1:8000 django website

Tags: html, css, django, web

I'm very confused on my django website right now. I have always used localhost:8000 to check my website and it used to work. Now whenever i make changes to the style.css file, the localhost:8000 wont update the website. Instead, it updates only when i open the website through 127.0.0.1:8000. Anyone know whats the problem here?

Comment: Check on other browser. If it's okay there then you need to clear cache OR hard refresh your page.

Comment: Try to clear cache and hard reload then your browser loads every file again and see your changes in the css files. Here is an articale about difference between localhost and 127.0.0.1 https://www.pixelstech.net/article/1538275121-Difference-between-localhost-and-127-0-0-1

Comment: ctrl+F5 for chrome ctrl+shift+R for mozilla

Answer (score 0):

restart your computer sometimes it happens when we work for hours or change the localhost:8000 to localhost:8081 or as per your requirement

Answer (score 0):

The issue is due to cache.
If you just clear cache or restart browser, the problem will be solved temporarily and might still come again and besides, that is a long process

A better option is to add stuff like a timestamp to your css link, then refresh the page, your css will update to latest on the browser.

`<link href="style.css?t=randomNum" rel="stylesheet">`